# Definition of Convergence a.s. in Counting probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

If we have probability space [0,1], P(A)=|A|, we have

$$Xn=n^{1/p}*1_{[0,1/n]}$$ Show that Xn converges almost surely. (p denoting any p norm here)

So i proved Xn converges in probability to 0 since $P(|Xn|>\epsilon)<1/n$ so approches to 0 right? Then If Xn converges a.s., it has to converge to 0 a.s. However, the answer says Xn converges a.s. with no explanation; but Xn can contain infinitely many 0's and $n^{1/p}$'s. So how would it converge a.s. to 0?

Answer (score 1):

For any $\omega$ except 0, for $n>1/\omega$ you have $X_n(\omega)=0$.

Comment: for n>1/w? you mean for w>1/n?

Comment: @TomWangzilin No, I said what I meant.

Comment: what is for n>1/w? and then the range is inclusive [0,1] which means Xn can not equal to 0? can you explain a little more?